# ctypes callback function crashes Python - "this" pointer parameter?

Tags: python, c++, this, ctypes, this-pointer

I'm calling a C dll from Python using ctypes and having some trouble passing the correct parameters to the `IBSU_RegisterCallbacks` function, defined below.

```
int WINAPI IBSU_RegisterCallbacks
    (const int         handle, 
     const IBSU_Events event, 
     void             *pCallbackFunction,
     void             *pContext);
```

It describes the final parameter as:

```
/* pContext Pointer to user context that will be passed to callback function.*/
```

A working C++ example calls the function like this:

```
RegisterCallbacks(0, 1, OnCallback, this);
```

So far in Python I have the below code (relevant section shown only), which crashes Python (no traceback) shortly after the event is triggered and `callback run!` is printed.

```
from ctypes import *

class IBSU(object):
    _dll = WinDLL('ibsu.dll')

    _C_CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(
        None,        
        c_int,                                         # device handle
        c_void_p)                                      # user context

    _register_callbacks = _dll.IBSU_RegisterCallbacks
    _register_callbacks.restype = c_int
    _register_callbacks.argtypes = (c_int,             # device handle
                                    c_int,             # event type
                                    c_void_p,          # callback function
                                    c_void_p)          # user context

    def _get_c_callback(self):
        def callback(handle,                           # device handle
                     p_context):                       # user context
            print 'callback run!'
        return self._C_CALLBACK(callback) 

    def register_callbacks(self):
        # keep ref to prevent garbage collection
        self._c_callback = self._get_c_callback()

        self._register_callbacks(0,                    # device handle
                                 1,                    # event type
                                 self._c_callback,     # callback function
                                 c_void_p())           # user context
```

What is the equivalent to `this` in my Python class that I can send instead of just `c_void_p()` in the last line of code? Could getting this parameter wrong cause the crash even after my Python callback function fires?

Comment: Generally a DLL will consistently using a calling convention. Are you sure the callback shouldn't use `WINFUNCTYPE`?

Comment: The context parameter is for lower-level languages such as C. It's pretty much useless for Python. You can pass a bound method or closure if you need context.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for pointing out `WINFUNCTYPE`, I'm in the habit of using the other. Are you implying that I don't _need_ to use context? That would make life easier for me, but not sure if the function requires it to be valid. Would `None` suffice then? If I did send a bound method how does one cast it to `c_void_p`?

Comment: `None` suffices; it gets converted to a `NULL` pointer. You can instantiate the `_C_CALLBACK` prototype using any callable Python object. This could be a function, which has a closure context in terms of its globals and nested scoping; a bound method that has the context of its `self` instance; or an object with a `__call__` method.

Comment: Thanks very much, good to know. With `None` and `WINFUNCTYPE` I'm still getting the crash though. I'm beginning to think this isn't to do with the user context parameter.

Comment: By crash, do you mean the error reporting dialog is displayed due to an unhandled Windows exception? Or is it a Python exception?

Comment: @eryksun error reporting dialog, so no Python traceback or anything like that. Not sure how to best debug that.